# Is this possible to create a private report filtering in Data Studio embeded report

Tags: looker-studio

I created a report in DataStudio and embedded it on my website. I activated the option "anyone with the link can view" so this report will be visible to my website users.

But I need to show my website users different data depending on their user ids and more important I don't want users would be able to see other users' data so if I used URL filtering users would be able to breach and search another user id to see his data.

Does anyone have a solution for this scenario?
In [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en) I saw an option to limit the report to users in my domain, I assume this will solve this issue, but I don't find how to restrict other domains.

Answer (score 1):

### Users are logged onto Google

If users of your website are already logged onto Google, use the [Filter by email address guide](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en) from Data Studio help center. This requires you to setup FILTER BY EMAIL and then have a field in your data can be directly used as an email filter.

### Users are not logged on to Google

If you want a solution where the users don't have to be logged onto Google, you will need to:

1. Create a Community Connector to pass the filtered data to your users. The connector should accept a short lived token as part of the config.
2. Create a dashboard with your connector and pass unique short-lived tokens for each user.
3. You should have an endpoint that returns the current user's data based on the token provided. Alternatively, the endpoint can return only the user's identify and you can query a secondary data source with a service account filtering for the user's identity.
4. Your connector should call your endpoint to fetch data only for the user/for the user's identity.

This [official guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials) demonstrates how to implement this in more details.

*Disclaimer: I work in the Data Studio team and wrote the above guide.*

Comment: Hi Minhaz, I think your guide is just what I need, but I didn't understand if there any missing part in the guide.
Will you maybe be able to share a video of what described in the guide? Or maybe just how the result should look like.
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a video on this. If you face any issues, feel free to post a question and tag me here.

Answer (score -1):

**First option is to add extra 2 fields to your data source.**

1. User_ID
2. Password

For example:

```
Data, User_ID, Password
$10,Daniel,123
$20,Alex,456
```

In your dashboard, you need to create two *parameters*:

1. User_ID_Parameter
2. Password_Parameter

Both *parameters* can set the default value to null, and accepts any values.

Then create a new *calculated field*:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(User_ID,USER_ID_Parameter) AND REGEXP_MATCH(Password,Password_Parameter) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Then create a new *filter* to the chart that you want to hide:

```
To include the above calculated field Equal to 1
```

**Second option is to use the Data Studio default [Row Level Security](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en)**

The only caveat is the users need to sign in before they can view the report.

Comment: The first option looks good but the prob is how easy to find the password, just for loop with the permutations. to find 5 digit password you need max of 34 billion attempts, do you know if Google blocks you after several attempts? 


 
The second option is problematic because I need the user to have login with his Google account and I don't want it.

Comment: You can have a more complex password, and Google Data Studio doesn't block you because there is no "sign in" button that will trigger spam, the backend will check if the User_ID and Password is matched while the user is typing it out.

Comment: Good and creative answer, but I would stick to the second option as the only one (the first option is unsafe).